# decode json including json encoded strings

Tags: json, go, decode

Hey guys I am getting websocket information from external Api and it's give me json response in this way:

```
 `{"name":"message","args":["{\"method\":\"chatMsg\",\"params\":{\"channel\":\"channel\",\"name\":\"name\",\"nameColor\":\"B5B11E\",\"text\":\"<a href=\\\"https://play.spotify.com/browse\\\" target=\\\"_blank\\\">https://play.spotify.com/browse</a>\",\"time\":1455397119}}"]}`
```

I am putting it into this struc

```
type main struct {

Name string `json:"name"`
Args []arg  `json:"args"`
}

type arg struct {
    Method string`json:"method"`
    Params par `json:"params"`
}
type par struct {
    Channel     string `json:"channel,omitempty"`
    Name        string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    NameColor   string `json:"nameColor,omitempty"`
    Text        string `json:"text,omitempty"`
    Time        int64  `json:"time,omitempty"`
}
```

and decode it with code

```
sReplace := strings.NewReplacer(`"{`, "{", `"]`, "]", "\\", ``)
strN := sReplace.Replace(str)
r := strings.NewReader(strN)
d := json.NewDecoder(r)
m := main{}
```

I am getting error

```
invalid character 'h' after object key:value pair
```

I know that the error is result of text field value. Is there any good way to clean it up or tell the decoder to ignore content of text field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application is parsing data containing the substring `"text":"<a href="https`.  This is not valid JSON.  The error message is complaining about the `h` in `href`.

Because the JSON value includes encoded JSON values, the application must decode in two steps:

```
type main struct {
  Name string   `json:"name"`
  Args []string `json:"args"`
}

type arg struct {
  Method string `json:"method"`
  Params par    `json:"params"`
}
type par struct {
  Channel   string `json:"channel,omitempty"`
  Name      string `json:"name,omitempty"`
  NameColor string `json:"nameColor,omitempty"`
  Text      string `json:"text,omitempty"`
  Time      int64  `json:"time,omitempty"`
}

str := `{"name":"message","args":["{\"method\":\"chatMsg\",\"params\":{\"channel\":\"channel\",\"name\":\"name\",\"nameColor\":\"B5B11E\",\"text\":\"<a href=\\\"https://play.spotify.com/browse\\\" target=\\\"_blank\\\">https://play.spotify.com/browse</a>\",\"time\":1455397119}}"]}`
var m main
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &m); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
var args arg
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(m.Args[0]), &args); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/oVC_IO-Pgy)

Comment: wow thank you very much I tried to figure it out whole day. This struc and json allways where hard for me :(